# How to use model equilevent normal php file => file.php without blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

If status is successful how do I use model in normal php file without using blade.If you can help with this issue, I'm very home. When the file is a blade, it cannot be accessed from outside. i need to store it in php extension.Because this file asynchronously receives post array from outside

```
  <?php
                use App\Models\Paytr;
            
      
                $paytr_ekle= new Paytr();
                $paytr_ekle->hash="dsa";
                $paytr_ekle->status="das";
                $paytr_ekle->merchant_oid="dsa";
                $paytr_ekle->save();
        
  ?>
```

Model File

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Paytr extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'paytr';
  public $timestamps = false;
  public $primaryKey="paytr_id";
}
```

Comment: why it is necessary to keep blade file inside public folder?
is that recommended?
if you want to put blade file then just put it inside resources/views directory

Comment: I can't do this because the file bildir.php receives post array asynchronously with post from outside.It only gets when in this folder.But in order to make my operations easier, I need to keep this file in the public directory and convert it to blade.

Comment: I would be very happy if you could help with this. @Ariful Islam

Comment: you are breaking laravel framework rules

Comment: Yes but I don't have a choice

Comment: can you help me

Comment: Use this trick: Name a web route `file.php` and then do a normal Controller / View for it. Output what the external site expects. It doesn't matter if it is not an actual file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel blade engine provides a configuration file config/view.php , where you can add your custom view directories in it, place your public inside paths array and you are ready to go. whenever laravel tries to compile its view files it searches for blade files both in resources/view directory and public directory

```
// config/view.php

'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
        public_path(),
],

// web/route.php
Route::get('ex-page', function() {
     return view('address.to.blade.file'); 
});

// as you added public_path to the paths array, 
// files in public_path and resources/view path are considered to be adjacent
```

Comment: Thank you.How should the route in web.php be?

Comment: Or edit myquestions.Please review it?

Comment: Your route must return a method of a controller or instead a closure which returns a view file

Comment: I edited my question.Please can you help me

Comment: Laravel is a MVC model framework, You must receive all your requests and its parameters through your application routes.

Comment: Yes, but a different site from outside is sending a post thread asynchronously. When the extension is blade, I cannot receive this post data

Comment: This route will only print the imported data to the database. It will not interact with the user in any way.

Comment: I just made the codes simpler. Any chance to review?

Comment: I don't suggest this, but as you want you can access your model class anywhere. access your model class by using its namespace at the beginning of your file. 
Ex. Use App\Models\User;

Comment: No brother, if you want to receive post data, create route assign it a controller method, inside controller method use an instance of Request to access the post.

Comment: I did as you said, but I can't add to the database. I edited the question and added my model file. This is very important to me, if you can help, you will save my day.

Comment: You can also have api routes, the third party website can send its information through the api routes and your application controllers can caught it up via Laravel Request facade

Comment: Do this, if you want to store post data inside the database you can do it in controllers, if you want to access post data you do it inside controller,

Comment: Is it possible for me to use model in normal php file as I said